# Android studio emulator not opening app

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am very new to Android development. I set up Android Studio and created a project, which should show Hello World text in the app. But in my case, emulator is not loading the app, even though I get the following message on the console:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 mins 59.924 secs

Even if I kept the emulator running for 10 mins or more, app is not showing in the emulator. I am attaching the screenshot of emulator.

[image]

My Android Studio version is 2.2.2 and MAC OSX is Sierra. I am lost with this for almost one week. Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: Android monitor didn't say anything more?

Comment: There are several things you could try:
1. Look at the command line for the emulator Android Studio prints, and copy it
2. Try running emulator with additional '-gpu off' arguments - without quotes
3. Try appending '-debug-all' and capturing the output. Please post it here  so we could diagnose it together.
4. While emulator's running, run 'adb logcat > some_file_name' command and share that file contents. That's the Android debug output, it might also help to understand the problem. Note: you will need to kill adb with Ctrl-C after a while as it never stops until the emulator is closed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the way I fixed is by going to:

`Device manager` -> *(locate your device)* -> `Actions`

And in `Actions` use the dropdown menu to locate `Cold Boot Now`:

[image]